# Change url tag name

Tags: php

I need to change this url from:

```
http://www.mydomain.ext/tag/mytag/
```

to

```
http://www.mydomain.ext/article/mytag/
```

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: What research have you done? The topic you need to learn about is `htaccess rewrites wordpress`

Comment: See http://codex.wordpress.org/Permalinks#Category_base_and_Tag_base for some assistance.

Comment: Thanks for replies. I know about htaccess and rewrites but is it possible with a function without modifying the htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with htaccess and/or rewrites—at least not directly by you.

Just go to

> Settings -> Permalinks

in your WordPress Admin. Then, in the *Optional* section, set `Tag base` to `article`.

Hit *Save Changes*, and that's it.

Comment: thanks! Omg... I didn't see that option before. I'm sorry, maybe I am really tired :D

Comment: No problem. It was not always there, though. Would you mind accepting my answer to not make your question haunt the site every now and then?